# Option values in JOptionPane

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, joptionpane

I am trying to use a for loop to get the names from my class file to a `String` array whereby and display it in the `JOptionPane` list menu. However, I am facing a `NullPointerException` but if I don't declare the `String` array as `null`, the compiler complains.

```
public void showWindow()
{
    String[] theNames = null;

    for(int i=0; i<person.length; i++)
    {
        if(person[i] != null)
        {
            System.out.println(person[i].name);
        }
    }

    String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select your name and click on confirm", "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, theNames, "Eric");
}
```

How can I solve this problem without me listing the option values one by one?

Comment: How and where are you populating `theNames ` String array?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with that line of code  :

```
String [] theNames = null;  
      String s=(String)javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select your name and click on confirm","Results",
              javax.swing.JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, theNames, "Eric");
      System.out.println(s);
```

NOTE: You must initial `theNames` unless you will get a `RuntimeException`.

and I notice that there is a Person Variable in your class.
can you explain to me why you initial theNames as a null ? what's the benefit of it int the method ?

Answer (score 0):

The options can be an array of any object, but make sure the toString() method is what you want displayed in the pull down menu. There is no need to list the options one by one or even to convert your objects into Strings.  For instance:

```
public class Person {

  String firstName, lastName;

  public Faculty(String f, String last) {
     firstName = f;
     lastName = last;
  } 

  public String toString() {
     return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }  
}

public static void showWindow()  {
  Person[] guys= new Person[5];
  guys[0] = new Person("Dick","Wall");
  guys[1] = new Person("Tor","Norbye");
  guys[2] = new Person("Chet","Haase");
  guys[3] = new Person("Carl","Quinn");
  guys[4] = new Person("Scott","Hanselman");

  Personp = (Person) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
     "Pick your favorite podcaster.", 
     "Java Posse",
     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
     guys, guys[0]); 

  System.out.println("You picked:" + p.toString());
}
```